# The "Big One" payday?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

How long does it take to get paid for the last heist? I finished the game and never got paid. Did I miss something, or just finish the missions too quickly?

Comment: I got the money after completing the last mission with Franklin where you have to choose one of three options.

Answer (score 3):

Lester has to fence the gold.  It takes a few days of in game time for this to happen if I remember correctly.  You'll get a text from the bank indicating the funds where transferred to your account.